# How to reference class in another class

Tags: java

So I made a wheel class that takes in two inputs(String, double):

```
public class Wheel
{
    private String name;
    private double radius;
    private double circumference =  2 * Math.PI * radius;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Wheel
     */
    public Wheel(String name, double radius)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.radius = radius;
    }
    /**
     * Accessor method for Circumference variable
     */
    public double getCircumference()
    {
        return circumference;
    }
    
}
```

and I want to referece it in my engine class as so:

```
public class Engine
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String[] name;
    private double tpl;
    private double totalNumTurns;
    private double distanceToTravel;
    Wheel wheel = new Wheel("Wichelin15", 15);

public double getDistanceToTravel()
    {
        this.distanceToTravel = wheel.getCircumference() * tpl;
        return distanceToTravel;
    }
}
```

but I dont want to have to put in the arguments as these two classes are going to be referenced in another class where the arguments for both will be put in.
Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "every time"?

Comment: sorry ignore that that was a mistake on my part

Comment: Please [edit] your question and try to clarify it if possible. I don't really understand it.

Comment: What about passing the Wheel object into the getDistanceToTravel method? That way you don't have to store a reference to it in your "Engine". It's a simple calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a constructor for `Engine` that accepts `Wheel` as an argument. Then you can use this constructor in the class that manages your objects' initialisation. For example:

```
class VehicleManager {
  Vehicle createVehicle(... you could put arguments here idk ...) {
    Wheel wheel = new Wheel(...);
    Engine engine = new Engine(wheel, ...);
    return new Vehicle(engine, ... other parts and attributes ...);
  }
}
```

That way you don't have to hardcode a `Wheel` object in your `Engine` class.

It also looks like you're using a `String[]` for the name of the engine instead of just a `String`, is that intentional?

Comment: no it was not thanks for that

Comment: Now that I think about it better, there's a design issue in here. I don't suppose your code is for production purposes but the `Engine` class shouldn't be the one responsible for knowing how many miles were travelled; That should be done elsewhere, like in a helper class that accepts a `Vehicle` object. For more on that you should search for Single Responsibility Principle.